# Rails deployment - best way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

There are several ways with which a RoR application can be deployed. What is the best way to deploy a Ruby on Rails application? Capistrano, normal SVN checkout, git pull or any other tool?

Comment: I use capistrano daily. It's neat and sweet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCM aware deployment using capistrano is simple and clean.

http://www.slideshare.net/hyfather/deployment-patterns-in-the-ruby-on-rails-world

The above article explores the other options like:

Distributing your app as a first class linux packages like RPM/DEB, or distributing the app as a WAR file or even releasing the entire app as a ruby gem.

The presentation even explains the pros and cons of all the options mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

As for me I use old-good Capistrano. It supports many CVS systems like git, svn .. Once created recipes helps me in every project. I just copy them to `config/deploy` folder and change meta info about project. It is simple and quite easy to use.